# Smooth curves in $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^2$ with projection onto $\mathbb{P}^1$ and exactly $2$ branches colliding

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

I am reading Andreas Gathmann's notes on [plane algebraic curve](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/%7Egathmann/class/curves-2018/curves-2018-c5.pdf). In particular, Proposition 5.16 on his notes says that a smooth curve of degree $d$ in $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^2$ has topological genus $d-1 \choose 2$.

The proof goes like this. Let $F$ be a smooth curve of degree $d$ in $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^2$. By a projective coordinate transformation, we can assume $[0:1:0] \notin V(F)$. Then define $\pi:V(F)\to \mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^1$ as $[x:y:z] \mapsto [x:z]$. So it looks like a covering space for $\mathbb{P}^1$ except for some points where $F$ and $\partial F/\partial y$ vanishes together.

Then comes the part I don't understand. It says that if we choose the coordinate transformation general enough, then we can ensure that at those places where $F$ and $\partial F/\partial y$ vanishes together, exactly two roots of $F(x,\cdot, z)$ will coincide. How can I see this is true?

Moreover, is this true if we are in $\mathbb{P}^n$ and I consider the projection $\pi:\mathbb{P}^n \to \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$, we can always find coordinate transformation to have exactly two roots of $F(z_1,\dots,z_{n-1},\cdot)$ at the place where $F$ and $\partial F/ \partial y$ vanishes together?

Comment: Choose the center of your projection away from bitangent lines and tangent lines at flex points of the curve.

Comment: @Sasha Could you elaborate the idea? In particular, what do you mean by "flex point" and "bitangent line"?

Comment: A point of a plane curve is a flex point if the tangent at this point has intersection of multiplicity $\ge 3$ with the curve. A bitangent is a line tangent to the curve at two or more points.

Comment: @Sasha I still cannot figure out how such choices make it. How should I see it algebraically?